# How install openfire server on mac m1?

Tags: java, openfire

environment : macOS ventura 13.5.2(macbook pro m1 chip)

language : java 1.8, java 11

Page referenced : https://download.igniterealtime.org/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/install-guide.html(installation guide)

download program : https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire(Openfire server download source)

I want complete Openfire server installation
I tried Openfire Server installation on mac but not working, What did I do wrong?

I tried code 'mvn clean package'(not working)

I tried code './mvnw verify'(not working)

I installed Ant instead mvn(not working)

I installed mvn with homebrew(maven install complete)

java 1.8v try
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpFgl.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHZoC.png)
'./mvnw verify' code result(java 1.8)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4G0c.png)

java 11v try
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4INg.png)
'./mvnw verify' code result(java 11) : print same message again and again

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT9D6.png)

I didn't find out Openfire server installation questions and answers
please help me

I want to complete Openfire server installation

Comment: Unfortunately, the [download link](https://igniterealtime.org/downloadServlet?filename=openfire/openfire_4_7_5.dmg) for [Openfire 4.7.5](https://igniterealtime.org/downloads/#openfire) is broken.

Comment: According to [this doc](http://download.igniterealtime.org/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/install-guide.html), you should be using Java 11 rather than Java 8.

Comment: @BasilBourque I appreciate your advice